# Delete all meshes in an operator?

Tags: mesh, objects

I am new to Blender Python. I would like to delete all meshes in a scene. How can I add for and if statement in a simple operator? Here is the simple operator template.

```
import bpy

def main(context):
    for ob in context.scene.objects:
        print(ob)

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```

Here is the "for and if statement" for deleting all mesh objects.

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        obj.select_set(True)
    else:
        obj.select_set(False)

bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

I don't know if this is the right method. I need help.

Comment: Replace the for loop in the `main` function by the lines at the end of your question

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe I placed it wrong :(